# Where can I find the JavaScript file regarding to block out of stock variations in product page woocommerce

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce

I need to modify this file in order prevent blocking some combinations out of stock

I tried to manipulate "add-to-cart-variation.js" in woocommerce/assets/js/frontend, but nothing occurs(I cleared it and javascript still works), I also tried to manipulate some php files regarding my theme but they dont change the class value to "disabled" (block product variation) but when I manually do:

```
wp_deregister_script( 'wc-add-to-cart-variation' );
```

The target javascript is died, but I can't find the file where wc-add-to-cart-variation is recorded

Answer (score 0):

I would use filter *woocommerce_available_variation* and change *is_in_stock* valye when I need, no messing with JS.

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-product-variable.html#source-view.303

Do the right way ;)

Comment: I'd like to turn all colors clickable, but just the sizes with no stock in combination unclickable, i think i can just solve that rewriting woocommerce javascript regarding blocking :(

Comment: You ming want to turn of stock managament on product, you could get error when adding to basket (from woocomerce side) with message "out of stock"

Comment: I'd like ending up with a ux of color vs size selection like this page https://www.usereserva.com/polo--pima-piquet0049162/p?skuId=47901, but cant find plugin to it, I'm on 2 days debugging javascript

Comment: I managed it, I erase all java script between line 318 until 498 in add-to-cart-variation.js, and add custom css/js based in user behavior

Comment: and this will work until you run WC update ;) GJ

Comment: I saved this script, generally very core functions from wordpress dont get updated